# Right Drawable in Android. Not Working

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-layout, android-styles

I am drawing a line beside a `TextView` using the `drawableRight` property. There are a number of `TextView`s in the table and all I want is column divider. Heres the `TextView` code:

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="units"
     android:drawablePadding="2pt"
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/linetable"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_margin="2pt"
     android:padding="2pt" />
```

*Linetable Code*:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line">

       <solid android:color="#000000"></solid>
       <stroke
            android:width="2pt"
            android:color="#000000"
            android:dashWidth="8pt"
            android:dashGap="8pt"/>

</shape>
```

So I expected to draw a column beside all `TextViews` and this may look like a column border. But it isnt working.

The images show what I am trying to achieve and what I have achieved.

I just need guidance. Thank You.

[image: The Spinner in the image is what I am trying to make]
[image: What I have achieved so far]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/).

Comment: Thanks, I discovered it but I was late. Lost a job :S